# system architecture stencils for omnigraffle?

Tags: microsoft-visio, omnigraffle

I'm looking for free stencils that I can use in omnigraffle to create system architecture diagrams: server, user, etc. So far I was unable to find any in Graffletopia or omnigroup's support pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look here:

http://www.sandrila.co.uk/articles/visio-articles/

It's a list of all the 3rd-party Visio stencils and addons that I know of, there are sections for network, computer and information architects, hopefully you'll find some suitable shapes there. Many of the shapes are free.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://thenounproject.com/ for ANY vector image. They do not come in sets (like a stencil) but you could build your own.